# Logging all headers via DelegatingHandler in HttpClient in .NET Core

Tags: logging, .net-core, httpclient

We have a requirement to log all outgoing http headers from HttpClient.

When implementing SendAsync of DelegatingHandler I use the request.Headers property to get headers.  To my surprise it seems that it only reports on my custom headers and not ALL headers going to the server.

What I wanted to do was have the capability to check the Content-Length header on the outgoing request before deciding to read and log it.  (Performance thing with large requests).

I was expecting this Content-Length header to be part of the standard Request.Headers property but it is not.

The only way I have right now of extracting the Content-Length is a Regex from the Request.ToString() which actually does list all the headers!

I'm sure there has to be a better way to do this...  There is probably something fundamental I'm not yet aware of?  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Well I feel a little silly because I discovered the ".NET Core" way of doing this after a few more debugging sessions:

I got the content length and type by:

```
request.Content.Headers.ContentType
request.Content.Headers.ContentLength
```

This still doesn't fix the oddity of the headers only reporting partial in the main message but my feeling is if you combine them you would get close to all the headers you would want for logging.